# Embed web liferay content within existing liferay web content

Tags: java, liferay, velocity

I'm trying to print a web content from inside another web content in Liferay 5.2.3. Following the issue [How to embed WebContent in Liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390704/how-to-embed-webcontent-in-liferay) i've tried:

```
set ($group_id = $getterUtil.getLong($request.theme-display.scope-group-id))
set ($webcontent-id = "ROBAPAGINES-COL-ESQUERRA")
set ($webcontent=$journalContentUtil.getContent($group_id, $webcontent-id, "", "$locale", ""))
$webcontent
```

It works when the embedded web content has no structure and template but **$webcontent** is empty when I assign an structure-template to the same web content.

I'd greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are calling below method for getting web-content.

```
 public static String getContent(
            long groupId, String articleId, String viewMode, String languageId,
            String xmlRequest)
```

But, you can use below mentioned method which accept templatedId.

```
public static String getContent(
        long groupId, String articleId, String templateId, String viewMode,
        String languageId, String xmlRequest)
```